# How does this supercapacitor over-voltage protection work?

Tags: supercapacitor, over-voltage-protection

I'm designing a capacitor discharge battery spot welder and came across [this video](https://youtu.be/NsTAyD2i3rc) on over-voltage protection for supercapacitors. How does the schematic shown at time [10:15](https://youtu.be/NsTAyD2i3rc?t=615) work? If I need to connect six 6F/2.7V supercaps in series, how can I simulate this in LTSpice?

Comment: The schematic at 10:20 is wrong and will not work. It is not the used circuit of the part shown at 10:15 (Z - diode instead of PNP, MOSFET instead of BJT)

Comment: @Jens Also found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjLiG-X7Htk)

Comment: In this last video the output stage is correct. It has another threshold, so no voltage divider at the REF pin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example simulation to get you started. Download all the files in one folder and opent the "balancer 2 stage.asc" in LTSpice https://drive.google.com/open?id=14SkodhG1R1RfIvOND3RLcgY9trETtKzz&authuser=teemu.p.latonen%40gmail.com&usp=drive_fs

Click "Run" and then click on the circuit to place a probe. Adjust resistors so that you get it to cut in on correct voltages. Click on the transistor to see how much power it is expected to dissipate. Check your selected transistor's datasheet to see how much it would heat up. Increase value of R10 and R6 to dissipate power in them.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain how this works?

Comment: The idea is that voltage over TL431 + Transistor EB junction (~0.7) need to be what you want for that cell. TL431 datasheet and running the simulation explains it better than my teaching skills. Remember that depending on the test conditions only one or neither protection might trigger. In the example case the lower circuit triggers, as it is protecting the capacitor with lower capacitance value.

Comment: Ok. Also found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjLiG-X7Htk).